# <a4j:commandLink> action not fired

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have an `<a4j:commandLink>` which I need to fire an action on my controller,

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:commandLink
        actionListener="#{controller.send(viewBean.id, cc.attrs.guid)}"
        onbegin="$.efc.busy($.messages.sending);"
        oncomplete="$.efc.busy('', true);">
        Send offer to this dealer
    </a4j:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

When I click on the link, the onbegin javascript is successfully fired but the action is never called. Here is my action from my controller:

```
public void send(String id, String guid) {
    if (id != null && guid != null) {
        ...
    }
}
```

My viewBean is view scoped and the guid comes from the component... What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

If I change the link to a button it works... but I need a link:

```
<a4j:commandButton
    action="#{controller.send(viewBean.id, cc.attrs.guid)}"
    onbegin="$.efc.busy($.messages.sending);"
    oncomplete="$.efc.busy('', true);"
    value="Send offer to this dealer">
</a4j:commandButton>
```

Comment: You cannot pass values using actionlistner, use action. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener for more details

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation :

"MethodExpression representing an action listener method that will be notified when this component is activated by the user. The expression must evaluate to a public method that takes an ActionEvent parameter, with a return type of void."

`javax.el.MethodExpression` (signature must match void actionListener(`javax.faces.event.ActionEvent`))

Comment: So is it possible to accomplish what I want using an `<a4j:commandLink>`? I tried using an action instead of an action listener and could not get that to work either. I eventually just switched to a `<div>` styled like a like and called a `<a4j:jsfunction>` onClick.

Comment: Not elegant solution is to have both link and button. Button with style display:none will be hidden. a4j:commandLink with onClick javascript which will fire onclick event on button and trigger round trip.

Comment: Action attribute of a4j:commandLink must evaluate public method that takes no arguments and returns Object. It's used for navigation purposes.